# Invoke a listener call programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android, listener, onclicklistener

I'm playing with Android and I'd like to know if there's any way to invoke a listener call programmatically, for example, having an `onClick()` listener and invoke a call to this listener without touching the screen when the activity is created.

Comment: Check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick%28%29 Don't know if you can do that with all actions that have listeners though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to get the set `OnClickListener`. So you need to store it and call your `OnClickListener` directly.

```
OnClickListener store = new OnClickListener() {/*...*/};
view.setOnClickListener(store);
store.onClick(view);
```

Answer (score 6):

Never tried that, but after assigning a `clickListener` to your object (for example a `Button`), call on your `onCreate` method `myButton.performClick()`.

Android doc :

```
public boolean performClick ()

Added in API level 1
Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs 
all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, 
playing a sound, etc.

Returns
True there was an assigned OnClickListener that was called, 
false otherwise is returned.
```

Comment: You should note that this is defined in `View` so this should work for every control. +1

Comment: +1 great tip but you should declare the `OnClickListener` before calling  `public boolean performClick ()`

Answer (score 0):

Although this is possible, I'd actually advise against it.  Listeners should be called from the UI but the business logic behind it is what should actually be called directly.  This would provide "separation of concern" between both layers.

You should be calling the code that the listener calls in it's `onClick` method rather than invoking the `onClick` directly.

Comment: Yes, I know, but having this little trick saves me a lot of work and I only need it for one ocasion so I think it's ok...thank you for your answer. Have a nice day!